# Run javascript function after the user input 4 digits

Tags: javascript

Here is the simple source code

```
<input type="text" name="verify" maxlength="4">
```

Is it possible that do not modify source code to achieve?
I found some sample on the internet that need use the onkeyup

```js
var x = function x(num) {
  if (num.length == 4) {
    alert("Test");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verify" maxlength="4" onkeyup="x(this.value);" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: By `Is it possible that do not modify source code the to achieve?` do you mean not modify the html (i.e., only use javascript)?

Comment: Yes, instead of typing `onkeyup="..."` directly in the HTML tag (which is a bad practice anyway), use JS to bind the event to the input.

Comment: What are you trying to do, I dont understand?

Comment: There was a website.
After input the CAPTCHA it not allow to press enter to submit, because the button made by javascript (Maybe?).
Here is the html code 
<a href="javascript:doLogin();">
<img src="../images/member/login.jpg">
</a>
So I think it maybe can use the javascript to achieve the login action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add an event listener using javascript.

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="verify"]').onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === 4) alert('test');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verify" maxlength="4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your same snippet(your same code) just adding a verification function and the respective call.

```js
const verificationFunction = (value) => {
  alert("here we are runnning the verification over " + value)
}
var x = function x() {
  var element = document.getElementsByName("verify")[0];
  if (element.value.length >= 4) {
    verificationFunction(element.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verify" maxlength="4" onkeyup="x()" />
```